# Create dynamic menu structure with ajax jquery

Tags: html, jquery, ajax, dynamic, menu

[image]How to create dynamic menu structure like

```
<ul id="sidebarnav"> 
      <li>
         <a href="#"></a> /*Root Menu*/
           <ul> 
             <li><a href="#"></a></li> /*Sub Menu*/
             <li><a href="#"></a></li> /*Sub Menu*/
          </ul>
      </li>
</ul>
```

I use like that in jquery but couldnt make algorityhm ..

```
            success: function (data) {

                for (var i = 0; i < data.d.length; i++) {
                    if (data.d[i].ParentID == '0') {
                        $("#sidebarnav").append('<li class="mainLi"> <a class="has-arrow waves-effect waves-dark" href="#" aria-expanded="false"><i class="fas fa-chart-line"></i><span class="hide-menu lang" data-key="' + data.d[i].MenuID + '">' + data.d[i].MenuName + '</span></a></li>');
                        var list = $(".mainLi").append('<ul class="goksel"></ul>').find('.goksel');
                    }


                        list.append(' <li><a href="/Reports/ProductBOM.aspx"><span class="lang" data-key="' + data.d[i].MenuID + '">' + data.d[i].MenuName + '</span></a></li>');


                }
```

when i use like that i got that output

[image]

Comment: what is happening with your code?, are you getting any errors or is it just not outputting anything?

Comment: i edited, my mistake... dont get any error but missing something